# Replicate STATA´s default margins output in R

Tags: r

The R package margins defaults to calculating Average Marginal Effects.
Average Marginal effects is calculated in STATA by using the option dydx(*)

That is:

```
STATA:
margins, dydx(*)
```

gives the same result as

```
R:
margins(model)
```

We are several R users participating in a STATA course where the margins command being used is just

```
STATA:    
margins
```

We have tried in many different ways to reproduce the default STATA output, but without luck. Can anyone help us or link us a relevant guide?
The vignette for the R-package "margins" only uses examples with the option ",dydx(*)".

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what Stata's `margins` w/o `, dydx(*)` exactly does, but maybe the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/) may help you? Perhaps even the [ggeffects::emm()](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/reference/emm.html)-command.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I just tried the ggeffects package, it looks awesome! I will try to work through some examples. If I get it to work I will post an answer here and reference you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stata's `margins` command performs two tasks:

- "Predictive margins"
- "Marginal effects" (of various kinds - average marginal effects, average partial effects, marginal effects at means, elasticities, etc.)

When you specify `margins VARNAME`, you are obtaining predictive margins, which are average predicted values over counterfactual versions of the dataset where `VARNAME` is fixed to its possible values. Consider the following:

```
webuse margex, clear
quietly regress y i.sex i.group
. margins sex

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =      3,000
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         sex |
       male  |   60.56034   .5781782   104.74   0.000     59.42668    61.69401
     female  |   78.88236   .5772578   136.65   0.000      77.7505    80.01422
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You might think this equivalent to simply taking the predicted values for all cases and then taking subgroup averages for men and women, and yet:

```
predict y_star
tabstat y_star, by(sex)

Summary for variables: y_star
     by categories of: sex 

   sex |      mean
-------+----------
  male |   64.5721
female |  74.88129
-------+----------
 Total |  69.73357
------------------
```

What's actually happening is:

```
replace sex = 0
predict p_male
replace sex = 1
predict p_female
mean p_male p_female

Mean estimation                   Number of obs   =      3,000

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
      p_male |   60.56034   .1301116      60.30523    60.81546
    p_female |   78.88236   .1301117      78.62725    79.13748
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thus the function is giving you *counterfactual* average predictions.

You can get the same thing in R:

```
library("prediction")
library("webuse")
webuse::webuse("margex")
m <- lm(y ~ sex + group, data = margex)
prediction(m, at = list(sex = c(0,1)))
Average predictions for 3000 observations:
 at(sex) value
       0 60.51
       1 78.93
```

Unfortunately **prediction** doesn't provide variances of predictive margins - just the margins themselves.

If you're specifying `, dydx(*)`, that's requesting marginal effects. Which can be obtained in a manner identical to Stata using `margins::margins()` as you already appear to know.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. This will surely help new R-users attending Stata courses going forward.